# How to display local stored images with the path out of my SQLite database?

Tags: image, sqlite, flask, view

I'm writing a little programm in Python, Flask which schould write all whatsapp message informations (using Twilio) in an SQLite Data Base. The storing of the other informations is working fine (ID, Rufnummer, Text, Datum). For the sent images I'm storing the path in the database an the images in static/Images.

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Rufnummer</th>
            <th>Screenshot</th>
            <th>Text</th>
            <th>Datum</th>
        </tr>
        {% for task in tasks %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ task.id }}</td>
                <td>{{ task.Rufnummer }}</td>
                <td>{{ task.Screenshot }}<img src="{{ url_for("static", filename="/Images/{{ task.Screenshot }}") }}" width="30" height="40"/></td>
                <td>{{ task.Text }}</td>
                <td>{{ task.Datum.date() }}</td>
                <td>
                    <a href="/delete/{{task.id}}">Löschen</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Most of my programm is from tutorials and copied together! :'D

I think that this part is not right: **filename="/Images/{{ task.Screenshot }}"**

[webapplication of the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yhapr.png)

Thank you for your Help!

Best regards,
Mathias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use string concatination.  Something like:

```
{{ url_for("static", filename="Images/" + task.Screenshot) }}
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast response! I also tried this but it's not showing me the image. If I replace the filename with "Images/Test.png" it shows me the test image.

Comment: @Mathias2207 Does `{{ task.Screenshot }}` return `Test.png` ?

Comment: {{ task.Screenshot }} returned the wrong path. It returned /static/Images/... Thank you very much!